# Getting the inventory count of last 30 days after 30 days from today

Tags: sql, sql-server

If today is March 28, 2022, I want to get the inventory count before 30 days from today for this instance it should be Feb 27, 2022 and only 30 days inventory count after Feb 27 is all I need.

like January 29 to February 27 only

Answer (score 0):

You are telling 30 days and again 30 days before 30 days i.e., 60 days

you can apply `DATEADD` like given below:

```sql
DECLARE @today date = '2022-03-28'
DEClARE @startInventoryDate date, @endInventoryDate date

SELECT @startInventoryDate = dateadd(day, -30, @today), @endInventoryDate = dateadd(day, -60, @today)
SELECT @startInventoryDate as startInventoryDate, @endInventoryDate as endInventoryDate
```

| startInventoryDate | endInventoryDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-26 | 2022-01-27 |

Comment: Please don't answer such poor questions.

Comment: @DaleK, I thought of providing some idea to him and help him to formulate his question better :)

Comment: You just encourage people not to make the effort to create a good question.

Comment: @DaleK, understood. Will take care in future.

Comment: Thank you for your response @VenkataramanR I will try this.

Comment: @DaleK I'm Sorry for my question.

Comment: @RixxxReyes don't be sorry, just use the feedback to improve your question. We're not here to criticize you, just to ensure you write good quality questions which Will get you the answer you need.